# Changing behaviour of a function according to other functions being called in an API

Tags: c++, oop, class

I'm writing some scientific code that generates / imports some data (let's call that X) to generate other set of data (we can call them Y). The problem is there more than one way to generate X and this generation method affects the calculation formula of Y.

I've developed a library that handles the data import and calculation stuff but, I'm unable to decide a sound mechanism for modifying the formula without user intervention.

What's the best way to handle such cases? I've implemented different functions for different generation methods for X, but calculation method for Y is single.

To clarify more, I want to implement the following behavior:

1. User calls one of the import functions that generates / imports X,

   - The magic happens and the formula calculating Y is updated somehow.
2. User then calls calc() function that generates Y.

All functions mentioned in this questions are concrete, simple and dumb in-class functions.

I'm not sure how to implements the trigger mechanism inside the functions that generate / import X and make the magic work. The method for storing the formulations are answered by helpful fellows @UnknownGosu and @Dima-Rudnik.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need something like an `IFormula` interface with an abstract function `calc()` so you can make you API get an `IFormula *`as a parameter? Something as: void DoCalc(IFormula* formula)?

Comment: Thanks @UnknownGosu, I'll consider that.

Comment: @SilentStorm, if I get you right, the method of generating `Y` depends on how `X` was imported?
Than the import/generation methods should return the concrete strategy/state.

Comment: @DimaRudnik There are more than one function that generate or import X. Calculation of Y depends on which (X generating / importing) function is called. I think you got me right. Hmm... That sounds logical. I'll think about that.

Comment: @DimaRudnik Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a form of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Just like @UnknownGosu pointed out. Define an abstract `Formula` interface, something like this:

```
class Formula
{
public:
  virtual double calc(double) = 0;
};
```

Than create a concrete `Formula`

```
class QuardicFormula : public Formula
{
public:
  double calc (double x) {return x*x;}
};
```

**Edit:**

In procedural programming, the same is accomplished with function pointers.
For example, an implementation of QuickSort that takes a pointer to a sorting function.

Comment: Actually the complete formula doesn't change, only multipliers change to be exact. I'm not rejecting this as an answer but, won't something like this be an overkill then?

Comment: If only the multipliers change, you can have the class represent [state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: Btw, this solves the problem of storing different formulations but doesn't define a mechanism to modify the actual calculation method. I just want the user to call, say, calc() and calc() shall use the correct formula automagically. Setting flags or pointers doesn't feel right. My question also tried to get answers for this problem :)

Comment: @SilentStorm - you just have to write the code that implements the magic. Since you haven't provided even a clue as to what triggers that magic and what the result is, it's very hard for anyone to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker I tried to improve the things a bit. Hope that helps.